# Navigation action/destination cannot be found from the current destination without any multiple calls and with the current destination being correct

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment

The navigation with NavController works well for other fragments within my app, but now I created a FragmentA that needs to navigate to existing FragmentB. There are different fragments that successfully call `findNavController().navigate(directions)` to FragmentB.
I create a navigation file specific for the FragmentA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentA_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="app.packageA.FragmentA"
        android:label="FragmentA" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
    </fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentB" android:name="app.packageB.FragmentB"
    android:label="fragmentB" />
</navigation>
```

When I call `findNavController().navigate(FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB())` , I have checked that `findNavController().currentDestination?.id` is the same as `R.id.FragmentA`, but I get this error

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination .debug:id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB cannot be found from the current destination 
    Destination(app.debug:id/fragmentA) label=FragmentA class=app.package.FragmentA
```

I checked also that there are no multiple calls to the navigation. The same error happens when the navigation file is made using the graphic designer of Android Studio. It works for other fragments and their respective navigation files, but not for the new fragment for which I have created a new navigation file just now.

Comment: `fragmentB` isn't declared in the `navigation.xml` file. Add it there or navigate to another navigation graph where  `fragmentB` is declared.

Comment: @Onik I added the declatioration of fragmentB, but it doesn't change anything. I have also tried to navigate to a navigation xml file where the fragment B is already defined, but the same error occurs

Comment: Can you add activity.xml file where you have used this navigation graph ? @krltos